# dialog.getWindow() returns null after dialog is created

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_ID:
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View InfoLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                .setView(InfoLayout );
        initInfoDialog(dialog);
        return dialog;
...

private void initInfoDialog(Dialog dialog) {
    //this line has the null pointer 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
```

Why is dialog.getWindow() returning null in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I see now the [getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getWindow%28%29) documentation is actually telling why (not the reason but why at this specific point). You can retrieve the window after calling [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show%28%29).

Comment: Well that says if the activity is not visible, which it is.  Also, if I call the same method (initInfoDialog) from onPrepareDialog, then getWindow() returns the correct value.  From looking at the source it appears that onPrepareDialog is called before dialog.show(), so I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: Are you sure `getWindow()` returns `null`? I tested it now and and can't reproduce that even when calling `showDialog(0)` in `onCreate`. If I take a closer look at your `initInfoDialog`, where does `dialog` become not `null`?

Comment: I ended up changing my code around a bit to achieve my same end goal, so I no longer have this exact flow.  For one, I am no longer using the Builder class, I am just creating the dialog myself via the constructor.  Either way, with my current code I tried putting a breakpoint in onCreateDialog and dialog.getWindow() was not null.  I don't know what to tell you, seems fine now, but I couldn't avoid it the other day - no matter if I restarted, cleaned, or anything.  For now I am moving on, but if I run in to it again I will create a sample project and reopen this question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found that the dialog must be visible, which it may not be immediately after 'show()'.  So I put my code in the 'onStart()' method of a DialogFragment.  Which by definition is called after it is visible.  Seemed to work fine.